# How to create a network diagram with tooltips: igraph, ggraph, networkD3?

Tags: r, networking, tooltip, diagram, ggraph

This question is a followup to [ggraph make filled arrow edges appear in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72395410/ggraph-make-filled-arrow-edges-appear-in-legend) (solved), but now I would like to add dynamic tooltips to the nodes to be able to show more information than can be done in a static image.

All the data, what I've tried so far & my R code is in this Rpubs document: https://rpubs.com/friendly/EDA-network

The script can be downloaded with the "code </>" button: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/912944_f40ed4eb53a242268ef57b7329d21d64.html#

Here is the network diagram I created using `igraph` and `ggraph`:

[image]

I tried using `plotly::ggplotly()` but most of the geoms used by `ggraph` are not recognized by `ggplotly` and all I got were points.

Here is a mockup of what I'd like to create showing a textbox tooltip when I hover over a node.

[image]

Can someone suggest either (a) how I can do this using the `ggraph` plot as a base or (b) a different network diagram package that could work.

Comment: Check out the `visNetwork` package: https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this helps, but for me it worked via:

```
ggg <- #output from ggraph
thism <- ggg + 
    ggiraph::geom_point_interactive(
         mapping = aes(x, y, tooltip = "string"), colour = "green",alpha=0,size=4)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(
    girafe(ggobj = thism, width_svg = 20, height_svg = 20,
          options = list(opts_sizing(rescale = FALSE))),
"test2.html")
```